# How to print XML Tag's attribute data and tag value sequentially in perl?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

Say I have an example XML Document,

```xml
<root>
    <subnode1 att1="sn1att1" att2="sn1att2">Subnode 1</subnode1>    
    <subnode2 att1="sn2att1" att2="sn2att2">Subnode 2</subnode2>
    <subnode3 att1="sn3att1" att2="sn3att2">
        <subnode31 att1="sn31att1" att2="sn31att2">
            <subnode311 att1="sn311att1" att2="sn311att2">
                <subnode3111 att1="sn3111att1" att2="sn3111att2">Subnode 3-111</subnode3111>
            </subnode311>
        </subnode31>
        <subnode32 att1="sn32att1" att2="sn32att2">Subnode 3-2</subnode32>
    </subnode3>
</root>
```

I want to print something like this

```
sn1att1  sn1att2  Subnode 1
sn2att1  sn2att2  Subnode 2
sn3att1  sn3att2 
sn31att1  sn31att2 
sn311att1  sn311att2  
sn3111att1  sn3111att2  Subnode 3-111
sn32att1  sn32att2  Subnode 3-2
```

I have written below code, which is able to print the attributes as described but not able to print the tag value (for example "Subnode 1","Subnode 2",etc).

```perl
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new( filename => 'raw1.xml' );

for my $node ( $xp->findnodes('*/*') ) {

    print "\n" . $node->getName . "\t";

    for my $attribute ( $node->getAttributes ) {
        print " " . $attribute->getData;
    }

    for my $property ( $node->findnodes('.//*') ) {

        print "\n" . $property->getName . "\t";

        for my $attributes ( $property->getAttributes ) {
            print " " . $attributes->getData;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please be careful when posting code and data. Stack Overflow's *markdown* swallows the closing `</root>` tag in your XML data because it is not indented. You should read [*Markdown Editing Help*](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) carefully

Comment: @Borodin Sure! Thanks for notifying though. *Modified

Comment: What exactly do you want from the XML, in English? Your XPath expressions are very general, and the only difference from your requested output seems to be that you are printing something like `subnode1` at the start of each line instead of `Subnode 1` at the end. There are no elements with a tag of `Subnode 1` and they cannot contain spaces anyway

Comment: XPath Expressions are general because, i am trying to make it generic for every other XML Document. Means, the logic should work for all XML Documents. Now,
`subnode1` is the Tag Name. And `Subnode 1` is the Tag value, if you notice in the XML 2nd line.
I want to print the tag values, along with the attribute values and that too sequentially as shown in the sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want

I'm not very familiar with [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), but I do know XPath

It looks like, for each element in the XML, you want to print a line that contains the values of each of the attributes, and of all child text nodes if there are any

That's not so simple as it may seem, as any element may contain multiple text children interspersed with multiple child elements

This code accumulates the values of all attributes and all non-blank text children into array `@line` and prints the line if the result isn't empty

I don't understand why your required output doesn't include my line

```
sn32att1 sn32att2 Subnode 3-2
```

Perhaps you will explain?

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::XPath;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new( filename => 'raw1.xml' );

# for all elements in the data
#
for my $node ( $xp->findnodes('//*') ) {

    my @line;

    # all the attributes of this element
    #
    for my $attr ( $node->getAttributes ) {
        push @line, $attr->getData;
    }

    # and all the non-blank child text nodes of this element
    #
    for ( $node->findnodes('text()') ) {
        my $text = $_->getData;
        push @line, $text if $text =~ /\S/;
    }

    # print it if there's anything to print
    #
    print "@line\n" if @line;
}
```

#### output

```
sn1att1 sn1att2 Subnode 1
sn2att1 sn2att2 Subnode 2
sn3att1 sn3att2
sn31att1 sn31att2
sn311att1 sn311att2
sn3111att1 sn3111att2 Subnode 3-111
sn32att1 sn32att2 Subnode 3-2
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Borodin! This is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Yes @Borodin, about the inclusion of last line in my sample output,
Actually, i am posting a question on stack overflow for the first time and am not very familiar with the functionalities of the forum. Might have missed it while copying. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @saumya: I think your first-time post is a good reason for the missing `</root>` tag, but you should be much more precise in general. For instance `findnodes('*/*')` means all grandchild elements of the current node, when you seem to have meant `findnodes('//*')` which is all descendant elements of the document root. You also need to be aware that XML documents mostly contain whitespace layout, which will appear as text nodes in the parsed document tree. In fact you probably still need to trim leading and trailing spaces from the text nodes in my answer.